# Django-tables2 RowSpan

Tags: django, django-tables2

I tried to make a table with rowspan when the cells in the same column have the same value.

Like in this image [image]

And i want to make it with `django-tables2`

I tried this code line but it shift the `X1` to the `field2` column at the second record.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for `rowspan` in django-tables2. While adding such a feature is a theoretical possibility, I suspect it is non-trivial and will bring quite some complexity.

You are welcome to propose a patch by opening a pull request though, but I will only consider merging it after I can inspect the actual implementation (and documentation, tests).

Comment: Thank for you reply. I think i will export the table with the `TableBase.as_html( request)`, modify the table to make `rowspan` on targeted row (and remove the row in duplicate to not shift the cells) and finally import this rework html table in `django-tables2` format. Do you know how can i change this html table rework to a `django-tables2` format ?

Comment: I think I do not understand your question

Comment: `print(type(my_table))
<class 'apps.tables.MyTable'>

my_table_html = my_table.as_html(request)
print(type(my_table_html))
<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeText'>
my_table_html = spanrow_table_function(my_html_html)

my_table = some_function_to_get_back_tables2_format(my_table_html)
print(type(my_table))
<class 'apps.tables.MyTable'>`

Comment: Just like the code block above this comment with i want to know it's how transform `<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeText'>` to `<class 'apps.tables.MyTable'>`  @Jieter

Comment: `str(my_table.as_html(request))` will return the html for the table. django-tables2 cannot create an instance of itself from the html representation, if that's what your asking...

Comment: yes it was what i am asking. Thanks for your reply.